# Anonymous manufacturers

Tags: business, consumer-protection, product-liability, warranty

Some manufacturers are not putting their names on their products: no contact numbers nor e-mail address for support to keep in touch with the manufacturer if something happens to your bought item(s).

Is there any legal requirement for the manufacturer to make themself known?

Comment: "Short" note on the original question: Particularly cheap items (including cheap electronic devices) are built in a single project. The manufacturer is not interested in providing support or improving his product and release an update. For the customer, that's a security issue (no information about possible recalls, no software updates for his new shiny smartwatch, etc.). The stuff is so cheap _because_ it gets no support.

Comment: @ordinary_guy Location? Different countries have different laws regarding consumer rights.

Comment: @nick012000 I'm located here in Asia, in the Philippines and the products I bought are made in China via online and some of these are from anonymous manufacturers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of. In the US, an example of a labeling requirement is [16 CFR Part 1101](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-16/chapter-II/subchapter-B/part-1101). In certain circumstances, there must be "public disclosure of information from which the identity of a manufacturer or private labeler of a product can be readily ascertained". Not everything is subject to this mandatory disclosure – it is driven by safety of consumer products. The Consumer Product Safety Commission summarizes some of the requirements [here](https://www.cpsc.gov/Business--Manufacturing/Business-Education/Business-Guidance/CPSC-Labeling-Requirements-Overview), and the strongest requirements are on "child products". A train car-load of pig iron would not be subject to such labeling (but then, you would probably know the manufacturer from the contract that you had to buy the iron). You can garner all of the safety regulations from [16 CFR Ch. II](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-16/chapter-II). [16 CFR Ch. I](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-16/chapter-I) is the regulations established by the FTC under the Fair Packaging and Labeling Act. This requires all "consumer products" to have a label, especially [Part 500](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-16/chapter-I/subchapter-E/part-500). This only applies to commodities in a package or with a label (not hardware from a bin or bulk sim-cards). §500.5 is the section that says that you have to say who the manufacturer is.